# Remove combobox animation on MahApps

Tags: c#, wpf, styles, mahapps.metro

I have a WPF application that uses MahApps framework for styling.

When I have a combobox with only one item it does a kind of animation. This animation increases the text resolution as you can see in the image bellow. For example, I use glasses: the first time it happend I thought I wasn't wearing glasses then I noticed it was an effect.

[image]

When I have more than one item there's no animation.

I don't know where to remove this behavior. I wasn't able to find something directly related on Google.

Comment: Have checked whether this issue is known in their bugtracker? You can post an issue [there](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/issues).

Comment: I posted the issue there. They added for the milestone 1.4.0.However this is a known issue more about WPF itself. Anyways, I think it's important keep this question here to help people in the future with older versions of MahApps.

Comment: https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/issues/2713

Answer (score 0):

I found something that solved the problem for now by removing the combobox animation.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <PopupAnimation x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}">None</PopupAnimation>

</ResourceDictionary>
```